# why image show space and go right, it should be fill up the gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to get my images to fill in the available space like the example website
[link view](http://labs.benholland.me/pinterest/demo-centered.php) 
how can i show my image without space and it will be come with different height.
it should like example website.

under you get my code . 
[Live demo my code](http://codepen.io/mostofa/full/OXaxvE/)

**code language html5**

```
<div class="blog_posts">
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="..." class="hg_t_1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="...." class="hg_t_2" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="...." class="hg_t_5" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="...." class="hg_t_3" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="..." class="hg_t_4" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="..." class="hg_t_2" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="..." class="hg_t_1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img src="..." class="hg_t_4" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

**code language css**

```
    .blog_posts img {
    width: 100%;
}

.blog_posts img.hg_t_1 {
    height: 220px;
}

.blog_posts img.hg_t_2 {
    height: 280px;
}

.blog_posts img.hg_t_3 {
    height: 120px;
}

.blog_posts img.hg_t_4 {
    height: 320px;
}

.blog_posts img.hg_t_5 {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: This post needs a lot of clarification. Please show us an example of what you are trying to do, as not everyone know what a "batter view" is. Lastly, use http://www.jsbin.com, which is a great resource for spinning up examples to show others.

Comment: sure , I am going edit my question again

Comment: http://codepen.io/mostofa/full/OXaxvE/

you can take a look about the problem .

Comment: Can you link to an example of a "batter view"?

Comment: why don't you google "batter view" and you'll quickly find out there's no such thing... obviously english isn't his first language and he clearly means "better"

Comment: either that, or he's trying to build some pancakes and is on the wrong forum

Comment: I want exact like this view  [see this link](http://labs.benholland.me/pinterest/demo-centered.php)  #iHowell  #Pamblam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand from your post but I think you're trying to get your images to fill in the available space like [the example site](http://labs.benholland.me/pinterest/demo-centered.php)  you provided in the comments.

I don't think this is possible with pure HTML5/CSS, but there's a javascript library called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which probably does what you're looking for.

Your HTML will look like this:

```
   <main>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nQSRbvc.jpg" class="width33" alt="">
       <!-- the rest of your images -->
   </main>
```

The `width33` class just sets the `max-width` of the image to 33%. This will allow the images to scale without changing the aspect ratio. And to initialize masonry just call it:

```
$('main').masonry({
  itemSelector: 'img'
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle example with your images: https://jsfiddle.net/fujtjf7q/

Comment: Good job. i need more help #mike

Comment: yes finally i solved it from your answer [link](http://codepen.io/mostofa/full/OXaxvE/)

Answer (score 0):

If you set both the height and width you will distort the image.

Set just the width and they will maintain aspect ratio.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lx09gpb/)

```
.blog_posts img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: NO , i didn't want it ..
check it http://codepen.io/mostofa/full/OXaxvE/

Comment: I want exact like this view [link](http://labs.benholland.me/pinterest/demo-centered.php) #Pamblam

Comment: if you can help me it will be better for . I am waiting for this . @Plamblam

Comment: @MDMostofa - The library is called Masonry. http://masonry.desandro.com/